# Simulate older API versions for testing

Tags: excel, office-js

I am developing an Excel add-in. My local version of Excel is running the latest so I have access to all of the most recent API calls. However, I want to be able to test the experience (and work around potential API holes) for a user that has a different version.

As an example, I am making use of the `getRangeOrNullObject` call which became available in v1.4 of the API. Is there any reasonable way to simulate using an older version? I want to be able to handle a bad range without making use of `getRangeOrNullObject` in a "real" environment.

I have tried pointing to a specific version, eg:

`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js`

However that seems to load the most recent. Other versions (1.2, 1.3) are a `404`.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>From the [Office Dev Center](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office):</sub>

> ### **Specify Office hosts and API requirements**
>
> Your Office Add-in might depend on a specific Office host, a requirement set, an API member, or a version of the API in order to work as expected. For example, your add-in might:
>
> - Run in a single Office application (Word or Excel), or several applications.
> - Make use of JavaScript APIs that are only available in some versions of Office. For example, you might use the Excel JavaScript APIs in an add-in that runs in Excel 2016.
> - Run only in versions of Office that support API members that your add-in uses.
>
> This article helps you understand which options you should choose to ensure that your add-in works as expected and reaches the broadest audience possible.
>
> For a high-level view of where Office Add-ins are currently supported, see the [Office Add-in host and platform availability page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).
>
> [image]
>
> ### ***See full article at the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).***

---

### Related links:

- Microsoft Docs : [***Usability testing* for Office Add-ins**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/usability-testing)
- GitHib : [**NamedItem Object** (JavaScript API for Excel)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/nameditem.md#nameditem-object-javascript-api-for-excel)
- GitHub : [**Excel JavaScript API requirement sets**](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.md)
- Microsoft Docs : [**Specify Office hosts and API requirements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I had come across that already, but that doesn't really answer the question. I don't want to set a minimum version or limit to a specific host. Rather, I want to be able to simulate those older environments to see how my program behaves.